# Tensor nuclear norm for a binary 3rd-order tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor, tensor-calculus

I am interested in the low-rank approximation of a binary(01) third-order tensor. Does anyone know how to define its tensor nuclear norm based on whatever tensor decomposition methods? Could anyone provide some useful references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize that I'm not more knowledgeable about tensor calculus, but I did find this on arXiv: [Friedland and Lim - Nuclear Norm of Higher-Order Tensors](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6072).  I hope you find an answer to your question.

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Many thanks! It is a very useful paper.

Comment: @LSpice Users need 50 reputation to comment on other people's posts, including questions, so Joey W didn't have the ability to comment. See [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3142/how-to-deal-with-answers-that-should-be-comments-by-users-with-not-enough-reputa).